# How to solve PHP conflict?

Tags: php

**hello dear**
   I am new in PHP and JavaScript. I have created a booking website using PHP/JavaScript but I have a problem when two persons or more select the period (for booking) that make concurrent produce conflict. So please help how to solve this problem with PHP/JavaScript code.

Comment: Don't see why this question should be closed, it's a badly phrased way of asking how to solve data conflict in a simple booking system.

Comment: @DLH: doesn't this involve more design solution rather than a coding solution (even if he is asking for code). Would a full code to handle this fit in few lines?

Comment: @Tom Gullen: sorry Tom, but where do you see the "question should be closed"?

Comment: @Marco, check the FAQ I think you see this sort of stuff at 4k rep

Answer (score 7):

**Hello dear**

The problem you have is a common one especially within booking systems.  There are a few things you can do to resolve this issue, but getting anyone to post complimentary code would be impossible without seeing your code first, so for now we will have to just provide you with ideas.

I will assume visitors are booking a commidity I will refer to as 'seats'.

**Reserve Seat**

User wants to book a seat.  Set the seats status to reserved.  This will show up on other users screens as already booked.  The reservation will expire within 30 minutes incase the visitor doesn't want it any more.  Be careful with abuse of this though, a visitor could 'reserve' all the seats continually, blocking anyone being able to buy tickets.

**First come first serve**

Allow everyone to book the seat, whoever pays for it first has it and then the other people have to repick a seat.  This option isn't very user friendly but is easy to implement.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: good answer, but 1st come 1s served is that easy?! If process A updates the DB row saying "SEAT BOOKED", and process B concurrently does the same they would both book the same seat. Do you use SQL atomic trasaction to roll back? Could you plz explain a little bit, it's interesting.

Comment: You would simply not change the status of the seat until payment.  When the payment is made, before you process the payment you check to see if it's booked, if it is, ask to reselect a seat, if it isn't, set it to as being purchased then process payment.  Revert seat to being free if payment fails.  This would suck for popular events where someone might have to restart many times.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: can't disagree more over your last comment. That's exactly the problem we face here. How can you be sure that we avoid this: process A reads the row and sees "SEAT NOT BOOKED", at the same time process B (concurrently running) does the same and sees the same "SEAT NOT BOOKED", therefore both processes go on and update the same DB row with the same value "BOOKED" and now tow users have booked the same seat. Redaing 1st the DB row does not solve the problem of concurrency booking. That's why I asked to explain.

Comment: @Marco, yes you are right, my appologies.  You can put a temporary lock on the record until the payment is received (this is different from reserving a seat as the lock will only exist for a very short period of time to avoid the rare instance of dual booking)

Comment: @Tom Gullen: interesting the lock, thanks. @walled: following Tom suggestion I found this inetersting artcile that explains DB locks for MySQL: http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/When_and_how_to_lock_tables.html

Comment: You can either use built in locks (which I rarely do) or write them yourself as an extra field which I prefer as I know I can rely on it :)